# Regex help: get stream url from soundcloud

Tags: regex

I'm using this expression `\"streamUrl":"([^]+)\?s` to get the soundcloud stram url.
This is the output from  RegExr: `"streamUrl":"http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/NKV9VhgN31Jt?s`
I need only the url (http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/NKV9VhgN31Jt?s) without `"streamUrl":"`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse stringified JSON with RegExp. If so, then why when you could just parse the json and use dot notation to get at it? In any case, some more info about which RegExp engine this is for and an example of what you are trying to parse would help a lot with the answers you get. JS RegExp for instance does not support lookbehinds, as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use look behind assertion:

```
(?<="streamUrl":").+\?s
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iF3bA5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace or simply use something like substr($url,strpos($url,"http"));

Comment: He didn't mention about PHP

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
http:[^\"]+
```

this will select the http url part only

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/zG3lD6